# Check if a symbol is available, to prevent dlopen lazy binding failure

Tags: symbols, dlopen, dynamic-library, undefined-symbol

I load a `.so` library using `dlopen()`. The library calls `myfunc()`. The function is available in version `1.0` of the loader. So calling `myfunc()` works. In version `0.9` however, there is no `myfunc()`, and `libdl` shows error about lazy binding failure.

Can I, within the `so.` library, check if `myfunc()` exists, and only then call the function? The function is not mandatory, not important, I can safely skip calling it if loader is in version `0.9` or lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On and `ELF` platform, you can use weak unresolved reference to achieve your goal:

```
// libfoo.c
extern int myfunc() __attribute__((weak));
int foo()
{
   if (&myfunc == NULL) {
     printf("myfunc is not defined\n");
   } else {
     // myfunc is available, call it
     printf ("myfunc returns %d\n", myfunc());
   }
}
```